# what are the major Difference between ordinary notes applications and a Xpage applications

Tags: xpages

I am new to Xpages application,
can any body tell me what are the major Difference between ordinary notes applications and a Xpage applications, so that i can understand and start from the bassics if any body helps.

Thanks in advance.
JB

Answer (score 6):

That's a very high level question.

You can create web applications using XPages. XPages "*is based on web development languages and standards including JavaScript, Ajax, Java, the Dojo Toolkit, Server-side JavaScript and JavaServer Faces*" (source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPages).

In order for you to start with XPages I will suggest that you read the following book:
[Mastering XPages: A Step-by-Step Guide to XPages Application Development and the XSP Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132486318)

I will also suggest that you look at the available resources and videos on [XPages.info](http://xpages.info/).

Have a look at my blog post on available resources for XPages too:
http://per.lausten.dk/blog/2012/02/learning-xpages-available-resources.html

Answer (score 0):

There's also a whitepaper on maximising the benefits of Domio 8.5.3 with XPages http://www.intec.co.uk/update-whitepaper-maximising-the-benefits-of-xpages-in-8-5-3/

Basically, it allows you to develop for browser and Notes Client with a consistent interface. In my experience, after the learning curve, developing for web in XPages is significantly quicker than developing for web in traditional Domino. The Extension Library reduces the time further, as do resources from OpenNTF. Plus with the Extension Library you can develop for mobile browsers using XPages as well.

There is a browser plugin coming in 8.5.4 which will allow traditional Notes Client applications to be used from a browser. However, I doubt you'll get as nice a user experience from that as you could get from XPages.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Partial Refesh, Works on almost any device and Speed.

Answer (score 0):

go to http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tlccsite.nsf/pages/free-xpages-training and we (TLCC) have a free course that introduces you to XPages and explains what they are as well as gets you started on your first XPage.

Howard